# How to check reply status in C# - Telegram Bot

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

How can I check the reply from keyboard using Telegram. Bot framework with C# in my telegram bot?

I have that code below to get the answer of user

```
if (e.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text && e.Message.Text == "/start")
{

    var rmu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

    rmu.Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]
    {
         new KeyboardButton[]
             {
                  new KeyboardButton("\U0001F525 Yes,I Do!"),
                    new KeyboardButton("\U0001F61E No,I want to Register!")
                    },


    };
    rmu.ResizeKeyboard = true;
    rmu.OneTimeKeyboard = true;
    var message = string.Format("\U0001F44B Hello {0} , welcome to our system. Are you registered before?", e.Message.From.FirstName);
    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, message, Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, rmu, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

}

if (e.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.From.Username);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.Text);

    if(e.Message.Text.Contains("Yes,I Do!"))
    {
        var rmu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

        rmu.Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]
        {
         new KeyboardButton[]
             {
                  new KeyboardButton("\U0001F512 Forgot username or password"),
                    },


        };
        rmu.ResizeKeyboard = true;

        Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Please enter your username in our system.", Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.ParseMode.Default, false, false, 0, rmu, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

How can I get the result of answer and is there any function or smthng in this framework?

Answer (score 0):

You receive the answer as a CallbackQuery.
First, subscribe to receiving callback queries:

```
Bot.OnCallbackQuery += Bot_OnCallbackQuery;
```

then process them like you would a regular message:

```
private static void Bot_OnCallbackQuery(object sender, CallbackQueryEventArgs e){
// some code
}
```